# Do I need a comma here: "Skies are blue and grass is green"

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Which one is correct:

1. Skies are blue and grass is green.
2. Skies are blue, and grass is green.

Stanford core NLP parses this sentence differently depending on presence of comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the conjunction **and** is followed by a subject-verb set then we place a comma before it. In this case the subject is grass and the verb happens to be **is**. In other words, if a coordinating conjunction such as **and** connects two independent sentences then use a comma before the conjunction.

Comment: This. You basically have three choices when trying to connect two independent clauses (complete sentences). 1) use semicolon (no conjunction) 2) use a comma followed by a conjunction (as this answer states) 3) make them two separate sentences with a period and capitalize first word of second sentence (beginning a sentence with a conjunction is fine but often is unnecessary). Which one of the three you choose is mostly up to your writing style.

Comment: -1 no resources cited. (Additionally, this is terribly prescriptive.)

Comment: @Clare, resources citing would be nice, but I like that is very prescriptive.